# how to put text and un-order list in the same line

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make them display in the same line, but they are not. The text float to the left is fine. But the list float to the right is not working great. I tried making them display in line, but still not good, they are just almost inline.
The following are html codes:

```
    <header class="Header">
        <div class="mainHeader">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <h3>Subtitle</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="subHeader">
            <ul>
                <li>Phone</li>
                <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
                <li>Address</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
```

The following are CSS codes:

```
.Header{
    background-color: #D5DBDB;
    height: 80px;           
    padding: 2% 0%;         
    margin: 2% auto;        
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader h1{
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #E67E22;
}

.mainHeader h3{
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
}

.subHeader{
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}

.subHeader ul{
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. In order for us to be able to help you, we need a few more things: a detailed description of what you currently have, a detailed description of what you want, and optionally other ways you tried that did not work. You can post some example code you are working with, or screenshots of the intended result.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

`.subHeader ul li{
display: inline;
}`

Comment: Thanks for helping Gabriel, but actually I was trying to keep the list display as a list, not in line.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed my problem. By setting text block width to 48%, and list block to 48%, and display them inline. They work fine now.